# insertBefore function issue

Tags: javascript, insert

i already have a form and a table and data from the form is added to the table but i'm trying to add a insertBefore function for my form but it doesn't work. could you please tell me what is wrong with my script?

```
function insertBefore(){
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    var td3 = document.createElement('td');
    td1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value;
    td2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('address').value;
    td3.innerHTML = document.getElementById('email').value;
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    table.tBodies [0].insertBefore();
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `insertBefore`, you have to tell the browser three things:

- A = Element to insert in to
- B = Element to insert
- C = Element to insert before

It should be in the form:

```
A.insertBefore(B, C)
```

for example:

```
document.body.insertBefore(table, document.body.firstChild)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know that the element you have to insert will always be the first element, you can use prepend() instead. this will always add the element you want as the first child of the parent element.